# Change Default Browser Programmatically Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

How would you change the default browser programmatically on Mac OSX.

For example from safari to chrome, or chrome to firefox?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know, but please make sure your app automatically uninstalls itself after overriding the user preferences.  It'll save me the bother of doing it manually.

Comment: The answer should be in the source code for Firefox and Chromium, if you fancy a trawl!

Comment: JeremyP, it's for browser testing of a new internal project. Not for public release. It's a hack I know, but need way to automate the process. Thanks for the benefit of the doubt ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(
             CFStringRef inURLScheme, CFStringRef inHandlerBundleID)
```

See also [Launch Service Reference Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).

Use `@"http"` for the `inURLScheme`, and figure out the bundle identifiers of Firefox, Chrome etc. to use.

You can also check which are installed using

```
LSCopyAllHandlersForURLScheme(CFStringRef inURLScheme)
```